# Download a folder from S3 bucket using wget

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, wget

I have made my S3 bucket public for certain IP. In the bucket policy, I have given s3:GetObject permission.

Now I am trying to download a folder from that bucket using wget.
Example:

```
wget -r "https://....."
```

But getting response:
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...

> 403 Forbidden

But, when I am trying to download a single file from the folder, I am able to download it without any issue.

Getting response:

HTTP request sent, awaiting response...

> 403 Forbidden

I expected the folder to be downloaded

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to "download a folder" in one request. You must retrieve each object individually.

The easiest way to download a folder is to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). You can either use:

```
aws s3 sync s3://bucket-name/foldername <name-of-local-dir>
```

or:

```
aws s3 cp --recursive s3://bucket-name/foldername <name-of-local-dir>
```

The `sync` command only copies files that do not already exist, while `cp --recursive` will copy all files. Both commands will also copy sub-folders.

**Update:**

To provide access without using AWS credentials, ensure that the bucket is publicly accessible to the IP desired address using a policy like:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListObjects",
                "s3:GetObjects"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "1.2.3.4/32"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

You *might* need to provide extra permissions -- if the copy fails, the error message will tell you what it was trying to do.

You can then copy with:

```
aws s3 sync --no-sign-request s3://bucket-name/foldername <name-of-local-dir>
```

If this is performed from the nominated IP address, it should be able to download the files without AWS credentials.

Comment: Using AWS CLI requires Access Key and Secret Access Key. What if I don't want to share that. I just want to create a script and provide it to the people who want to download it, without any login credentials?

Comment: @NikhilMittal If the bucket is public, they can add the `--no-sign-request` argument to the CLI command to access the bucket without credentials. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html

Comment: Note that to do that you'll need more than just s3:GetObject permission.  You'll need, at a minimum, you need to grant access to s3:ListObjects, and s3:ListAllMyBuckets (for all buckets).